# Good Practices to secure a Gaming Web Server, Memcached Server & MySQL Server

Tags: webserver, sql-server, server

We have developed Game for Facebook platform. We have several Gaming Web Server, Memcached Server & MySQL Server.

Here we have to work with **facebook Payment API**.

We need to secure enough our Gaming Web Server, Memcached Server & MySQL Server.

- We have SSL Certificate
- We Monitors Logs Everyday

Is those enough, or any suggestion from you please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make sure you have these things:

- Firewall
- [Host Based Intrusion Detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host-based_intrusion_detection_system) system on all your machines ([OSSEC](http://www.ossec.net/) is a free one, but you have to tweak the rules a little)
- [Web Application Firewall](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Web_Application_Firewall)

These solutions will significantly reduce the chance of a succesful attack by scanners etc. To have reasonable assurance you should also invest in a pentest.

Now since you have different servers, you should have frontend and backend servers. The backend can contain your MySQL servers since no users should have direct access to them.

Comment: +1 for Nice Answer. Also like the sentence "you should have frontend and backend servers. The backend can contain your MySQL servers since no users should have direct access to them."

Comment: Would you explain details "Host Based Intrusion Detection system" ?

Comment: @MahbuburRAaman check the link I added to the answer. I think the guys of OSSEC can explain it a lot better than me.

Comment: Depending on the amount of logs and your budget a tool like splunk to analyse logs can be interesting too

Answer (score 1):

I think you first need to look at the basics, such as having good firewall rules, keeping your software up to date etc. But this is the case with any server.

More specifically for you, my guess would be that the code for your game would be the most likely entry point for people who are up to no good. Examples are XSS, SQL injections etc. This is what i would focus on. If you work in a team, check eachothers code to make sure that the number of possible security holes is reduced as much as possible.